# @Autowired - No qualifying bean of type found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, autowired

I've started my project by creating entities, services and JUnit tests for services using Spring and Hibernate. All of this works great.
Then I've added spring-mvc to make this web application using many different step-by-step tutorials, but when I'm trying to make Controller with `@Autowired` annotation, I'm getting errors from Glassfish during deployment. I guess that for some reason Spring doesn't see my services, but after many attempts I still can't handle it.

Tests for services with

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/beans.xml"})
```

and

```
@Autowired
MailManager mailManager;
```

works properly.

Controllers without `@Autowired` too, I can open my project in web browser without trouble.

/src/main/resources/beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties" />
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.com.radzikowski.webmail">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>
    
    <!--<context:component-scan base-package="pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.service" />-->
    
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Persistance Unit Manager for persistance options managing -->
    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Entity Manager Factory for creating/updating DB schema based on persistence files and entity classes -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="WebMailPU"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <!--<property name="schemaUpdate" value="true" />-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.domain" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

</beans>
```

/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.com.radzikowski.webmail" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>
    
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.service.AbstractManager

```
package pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.service;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

/**
 * Master Manager class providing basic fields for services.
 * @author Maciej Radzikowski <maciej@radzikowski.com.pl>
 */
public class AbstractManager {

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

}
```

pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.service.MailManager

```
package pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
@Transactional
public class MailManager extends AbstractManager {
    // some methods...
}
```

pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.HomeController

```
package pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.service.MailManager;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    public MailManager mailManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homepage(ModelMap model) {
        return "homepage";
    }

}
```

Error:

> SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app
> SEVERE:   Undeployment failed for context /WebMail
> SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.service.MailManager pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.controller.HomeController.mailManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.service.MailManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Sorry for a lot of code, but I don't know what can cause that error anymore.

**Added**

I've created the interface:

```
@Component
public interface IMailManager {
```

added implements:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class MailManager extends AbstractManager implements IMailManager {
```

and changed autowired:

```
@Autowired
public IMailManager mailManager;
```

But it still throws errors (also when I've tried with `@Qualifier`)

> ..Could not autowire field: public
> pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.service.IMailManager
> pl.com.radzikowski.webmail.controller.HomeController.mailManager...

I've tried with different combinations of `@Component` and `@Transactional` too.

Shouldn't I include beans.xml in web.xml somehow?

Comment: How are you loading beans.xml?

Comment: now how about to leave only one of `MailManagerInterface` and `IMailManager`? :)

Comment: Sorry, I badly pasted code. In my program there is `IMailManager` everywhere.

Comment: ah, exactly.. add `<import resource="classpath:/beans.xml"/>` to `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`

Comment: By the way, did you try @emd decision?

Comment: Works great, thank you. With import works even without interfaces. And I will use emd suggestion during unit tests.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You should autowire interface `AbstractManager` instead of class `MailManager`. If you have different implemetations of `AbstractManager` you can write `@Component("mailService")` and then `@Autowired @Qualifier("mailService")` combination to autowire specific class.

This is due to the fact that Spring creates and uses proxy objects based on the interfaces.

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't work (same error). I added changes in post. Maybe I don't include / search something in my project properly?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to do something like `@Autowired AbstractManager[] abstractManagers` that contains all its implementations.

Comment: @WoLfPwNeR It should work exactly as you wrote. See [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation)

Comment: Why not `MailManager`?

Comment: I have two `@Service` classes implementing the same interface. Both are `@Autowired` in another class. Initially it caused the same problem as the original post when I used the specific class type. Following this answer, I changed to use Interface type with different `@Qualifier("myServiceA")` and `@Qualifier("myServiceB")`, and the problem was resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

I had this happen because my tests were not in the same package as my components.  (I had renamed my component package, but not my test package.)  And I was using `@ComponentScan` in my test `@Configuration` class, so my tests weren't finding the components on which they relied.

So, double check that if you get this error.

Comment: This worked for me. My tests failed when I refactored code to move to a new package name because I was using old package name in @ComponentScan.

Comment: How to use `@Configuration` class from `src/main` in `src/test`?

Answer (score 10):

The thing is that both the application context and the web application context are registered in the WebApplicationContext during server startup. When you run the test you must explicitly tell which contexts to load.

Try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/beans.xml", "/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml"})
```

Comment: How to do it if a am using Spring Boot?

Comment: I forget about configuring component scan for maven dependencies and struggle with this like once a year.

Comment: If you're talking about the application itself and not integration tests, for Spring boot you can do it like this:  `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.package.one", "com.package.two" })`

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same issue while auto-wiring the class from one of my jar file.
I fixed the issue by using @Lazy annotation:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private IGalaxyCommand iGalaxyCommand;
```

Comment: Weirdly enough, I needed this when migrating from Hibernate v4.3/Spring v4.3 to Hibernate v5.4/Spring v5.3... the solution was either to add this `@Lazy`, or to enable the DEBUG logs for `org.springframework.data.repository` ?!? timing / race-condition issue I guess? (adding logs slowed things down enough to delay things to fix the issue?) sooo weird

Comment: How does using @Lazy solve this particular problem? I've had the same problem and it helped - I just don't understand how.

Answer (score 7):

This may help you:

I have the same exception in my project. After searching while I found that I am missing the `@Service` annotation to the class where I am implementing the interface which I want to `@Autowired`.

In your code you can add the `@Service` annotation to `MailManager` class.

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class MailManager extends AbstractManager implements IMailManager {
```

Comment: The `@Service` annotation contains `@Component`. Having both is redundant.

Answer (score 7):

Faced the same issue in my spring boot application even though I had my package specific scans enabled like

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.*"})
```

But, the issue was resolved by providing `@ComponentScan({"com.*"})` in my Application class.

Answer (score 6):

Spent much of my time with this! My bad! Later found that the class on which I declared the annotation `Service` or `Component` was of type abstract. Had enabled debug logs on Springframework but no hint was received. Please check if the class if of abstract type. If then, the basic rule applied, can't instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: You saved my day sir, this is so hard to detect!

Answer (score 3):

Correct way shall be to autowire AbstractManager, as Max suggested, but this should work fine as well.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="mailService")
public MailManager mailManager;
```

and

```
@Component("mailService")
@Transactional
public class MailManager extends AbstractManager {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try annotating only your concrete implementation with `@Component`? Maybe the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10322456/2619091) could help. It is kind of a similar problem. I usually put Spring annotations in the implementation classes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10322456/2619091

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me was to add all the relevant classes to the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation for the testing class.

The class to test, `MyClass.java`, had two autowired components: `AutowireA` and `AutowireB`. Here is my fix.

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyClass.class, AutowireA.class, AutowireB.class})
public class MyClassTest {
...
}
```

Comment: This was a lifesaver and resolved my issue. Incase it helps anyone, I was having same issue in my ControllerTest class with the jackson ObjectMapper dependency not being found, which I had as autowired. The above solution of adding the ObjectMapper with  @ContextConfiguration resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that here

```
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.com.radzikowski.webmail" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

all annotations are first disabled by `use-default-filters="false"` and then only `@Controller` annotation enabled. Thus, your `@Component` annotation is not enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to this recently, and as it turned out, I've imported the wrong annotation in my service class. Netbeans has an option to hide import statements, that's why I did not see it for some time.

I've used `@org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service` instead of `@org.springframework.stereotype.Service`.

Answer (score 1):

- One reason BeanB may not exist in the context
- Another cause for the exception is the existence of two bean
- Or definitions in the context  bean that isn’t defined is requested by name from the Spring context

see more this url:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception

Answer (score 1):

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />
```

same issue arrived , i solved it by keeping the annotations intact and in dispatcher **servlet** :: keeping the base package scan as `com.*.` this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of @Autowire MailManager mailManager, you can mock the bean as given below:

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;

::
::

@MockBean MailManager mailManager;
```

Also, you can configure `@MockBean MailManager mailManager;` separately in the `@SpringBootConfiguration` class and initialize like below:

```
@Autowire MailManager mailManager
```

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me when I had two methods with the same name marked `@Bean` in different `@Configuration` classes. It appears that one of the declarations was overriding the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing your controller.
Don't forget to use @WebAppConfiguration on your test class.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen because I added an autowired dependency to my service class but forgot to add it to the injected mocks in my service unit test.

The unit test exception appeared to report a problem in the service class when the problem was actually in the unit test. In retrospect, the error message told me exactly what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem,
Issue SOlved using below steps:

1. Check the class/Interface that you are auto wiring
2. For Interface Business logic we should use `@service` when it extends the Interface method.
3. For Dao that is a Database handling class we should use `@Repository`.

→ We can use `@Service`, `@Repository` and `@Component` annotation effectively and solve this issue very fast.

Answer (score 0):

if you are testing the DAO layer you must use `@Autowire` annotation like this:

```
@Autowired
private FournisseurDao fournisseurDao;
```

Don't inject a repository element in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced similar issue in multi-module project w/ `No qualifying bean of type` like:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.stockclient.repository.StockPriceRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

and the reason for this error was missing annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories` in my specific use case.

**To clarify:** this annotation needs to be added for enabling auto configuration support for `Spring Data JPA` required to know the path of `JPA` repositories. By default, it will scan only the main application package and its sub packages for detecting the `JPA` repositories.

For more details you can refer, for instance, to this [article](https://chathurangat.wordpress.com/2017/11/13/what-are-the-uses-of-entityscan-and-enablejparepositories-annotations/).

Answer (score 0):

Was configuring a non-SpringBoot, non-JPA, Hibernate application and the error was seen with injecting a DAO class implementation defined with `@Repository`.

Moving the declaration from `@Repository` to `@Component` worked. Remember that you would lose some features as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56199502/can-we-use-dao-without-repository-annotations-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

As an industrial standard or the best practice is to use Interfaces which are implemented by java classes, like Controller, service and repository. in my case i have @Autowired service class, that's what bringing the error.

Fixed by @Autowired service interface, instead of service class.
and don't forget to add @Service for your service class.