# Why @MockBean does not mock my target repository class (returns null)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mockito

Here is the class I want to test

```
@Component
public class PermissionCheck {

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    public boolean hasPermission(int myEntityID) {
        MyEntity myEntity = myEntityRepository.findById(myEntityId);
        return myEntity != null;
    }
}
```

Here is the test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class PermissionCheckTests {

    @MockBean
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    private PermissionCheck permissionCheck;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        this.permissionCheck = new PermissionCheck();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldHasPermission() {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();

        when(this.myEntityRepository.findById(any())).thenReturn(myEntity);
        assertTrue(this.permissionCheck.hasPermission(0));
    }
}
```

And when I run this test I got

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PermissionCheck.hasPermission(PermissionCheck.java:line1)
    at PermissionCheckTests.shouldHasPermission(PermissionCheckTests.java:line2)
```

In the above, line1 and line2 refer to these two lines

```
        MyEntity myEntity = myEntityRepository.findById(myEntityId);
```

```
        assertTrue(this.permissionCheck.hasPermission(0));
```

And using debugger I see that when entering `PermissionCheck.hasPermission` from `PermissionCheckTests.shouldHasPermission`, the repository field

```
    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;
```

is null.

I created these classes by referring to others existing codes, from different places, and without really understanding how to the annotations (partially due to running out of time), so if someone can tell me not only how to fix, but also *why* I'm wrong, I would really appreciate it!

Edit:

I made the change suggested by @Nikolas Charalambidis (thank you!), so my `PermissionCheck` class now looks exactly like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class PermissionCheckTests {

    @Autowired                                     // you need to autowire
    private PermissionCheck permissionCheck;       // and it uses @MockBean dependency

    @MockBean                                      // if no such @MockBean exists
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository; // the real implementation is used

    @Test
    public void shouldHasPermission() {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();

        when(this.myEntityRepository.findById(any())).thenReturn(myEntity);
        assertTrue(this.permissionCheck.hasPermission(0));
    }
}
```

But I then got the following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'PermissionCheckTests': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'permissionCheck'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'PermissionCheck' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), 
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="")}
```

With a little bit search, from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20333975/10349064), I feel like I should not @Autowired `PermissionCheck`, since it is a class, not an interface.

Does that mean I have to create an interface, @Autowired it and let `PermissionCheck` implement it? It seems redundant to me, since I don't see why I need such an interface. Is there a way to make it work without creating a new interface which I will solely use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance of class `PermissionCheck` is not properly injected. The tests use the Spring container in the same way as the production code. The following line would not inject the `myEntityRepository`.

```
this.permissionCheck = new PermissionCheck();
```

[Spring: NullPointerException occurs when including a bean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38585975/3764965) partly answers your question. You need to `@Autowire` the thing.

The Spring test context is no different. As long as `@MockBean` `MyEntityRepository` exists as a mocked bean, the `PermissionCheck` will be autowired in the standard way using the mocked class *in precedence* over the existing bean *in the test scope*.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class PermissionCheckTests {

    @Autowired                                     // you need to autowire
    private PermissionCheck permissionCheck;       // and it uses @MockBean dependency

    @MockBean                                      // if no such @MockBean exists
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository; // the real implementation is used

    @Test
    public void shouldHasPermission() {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();

        when(this.myEntityRepository.findById(any())).thenReturn(myEntity);
        assertTrue(this.permissionCheck.hasPermission(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! But I still having errors... Could you please have a look on the updated part of the question?

Comment: I also ask [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66223823/why-autowired-raises-unsatisfieddependencyexception-even-the-class-does-not-im) for that

Answer (score 0):

in my case i was using lombok i was added @NoArgsConstructor
to the class that that i had injected my repository.

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor // what cuased the null pointer
public class ParcelUtil {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderEventConsumer.class);

    private ParcelRepository parcelRepository;

}
```

my test:

```
 @SpringBootTest
    @DirtiesContext
    public class OrderEventConsumerTest extends SpringBootEmbeddedKafka {
        @MockBean
        private ParcelRepository parcelRepository;
    
    }

   

    @Test
        public void update_parcel_inride_to_delivered_nxb() throws JsonProcessingException {
    
            //given
            List<Parcel> parcels = DataUtil.createParcel_inride_and_draft_nxb();
                Mockito
.when(parcelRepository.findFirstByParcelGroupId("12"))
.thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(parcels.get(0))); //where i got null pointer
 

   
    
    }

}
```