# Why @Autowired raises UnsatisfiedDependencyException, even the class does not implement any interface?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mockito, autowired

Here is the class I want to test

```
@Component
public class PermissionCheck {

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    public boolean hasPermission(int myEntityID) {
        MyEntity myEntity = myEntityRepository.findById(myEntityId);
        return myEntity != null;
    }
}
```

Here is the test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class PermissionCheckTests {

    @Autowired                                     // you need to autowire
    private PermissionCheck permissionCheck;       // and it uses @MockBean dependency

    @MockBean                                      // if no such @MockBean exists
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository; // the real implementation is used

    @Test
    public void shouldHasPermission() {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();

        when(this.myEntityRepository.findById(any())).thenReturn(myEntity);
        assertTrue(this.permissionCheck.hasPermission(0));
    }
}
```

And when I run this test I got

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'PermissionCheckTests': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'permissionCheck'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'PermissionCheck' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), 
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="")}
```

From other SO questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387431/spring-autowiring-class-vs-interface), I see that this happens when the target class implements an interface. But as we can see from the code, `PermissionCheck` does not implement any interface, so why is the exception still thrown?

Does that mean I have to create an interface, @Autowired it and let `PermissionCheck` implement it? It seems redundant to me, since I don't see why I need such an interface. Is there a way to make it work without creating a new interface which I will solely use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` does not automatically load your configurations/beans/properties unless accompanied with annotations that specifically do that, such as `@ContextConfiguration` and `@TestPropertySource`.

If yours is a Spring Boot application and you want to load the whole context along with all properties, you can simply add the `@SpringBootTest` annotation to your test class.

References:

- [Spring Testing Annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-spring)
- [Spring Boot Testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications)